# "I like swimming breaststroke" or "I like swimming the breaststroke"?

Tags: articles, adverbs, definite-article

Tell me please if I need to use *the* before the types of swimming techniques when they are used as adverbs? For example:

> I like swimming (**the**) breaststroke.
>
> I prefer to swim (**the**) front crawl stroke.

If the sentences don't sound natural at all, how would a native English speaker say them?

Comment: Very formal language might refer to “the breaststroke” but the article is almost never used in Australian English usage - it is just “breaststroke”. I have never heard of “front crawl stoke”. It sounds like a description of the stoke not its name.

Comment: I just researched “front crawl” and found it is a widely accepted name for the stroke I call “Australian crawl” or “overarm” (for me, the ordinary way to swim). You don’t normally refer to “front crawl stroke” but just use “front crawl” as the name of the stroke.